# how to convert unix timestamp to cet time in php?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a simple question for you. I have a unix timestamp variable in php, let me call it $unix, which contains the current unix timestamp (seconds passed after 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC), that by definition is UTC time. I want to convert it to a date string in CET time, like "29/03/19 14:50". It is crucial to have the CET format for me, not changing when the daylight saving time (DST) begins. In other words, the date I want is UTC+1 out DST, and during DST, and this has to be done automatically. 
I was thinking about using this function:

```
date_create_from_format ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )
```

so I should write something like:

```
date_create_from_format ('d/m/y h:i' , $unix, 'CET');
```

Am I wrong? What does not convince me is that in [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) it is clarely written that:

> The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the time parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

Is there a way to do what I want?
Thank you!

Comment: The 3rd argument to `date_create_from_format()` is a DateTimeZone object. You can't pass the string `'CET'` to it.

Comment: check Carbon https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Ok, I wrote `date_create_from_format('U',time(),new DateTimeZone('CET'))->format('d/m/y h:i')` and it gives me 29/03/19 01:47, while it should be 29/03/19 14:47! note that this is the same result as if I write `date_create_from_format('U',time())->format('d/m/y h:i')`.

Comment: `h` is 12 hour format, you want `H` …

Comment: 04FS Thank you!! there was the problem! now I solved with: `date_create_from_format('U',time()+3600)->format('d/m/y H:i');` this returns perfectly the CET time

Answer (score 0):

First convert your date time in php data time format...

```
 gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp);
```

Now you can display PHP date time from UTC time to specific timezone.

```
$date_time_format = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time_zone_from="UTC";
$time_zone_to='Asia/Kolkata';
$display_date = new DateTime($date_time_format, new DateTimeZone($time_zone_from));
$display_date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($time_zone_to));
echo $display_date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should bring your desired result:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'CET' );
echo date('d/m/y h:i', $unix );
```